# How to type math expressions within ( | )

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I am brand new to LaTeX after typing in Word on mac using Equation Editor.  Journals now seem to want LaTeX, so I am trying to learn it.  I am trying to type a mathematical expression `A(Y|X)`.  I typed: `$A\left(Y|X\right)$`  I get `A(Y` correctly, i.e. italicized, but no `|` and the `X` is not italicized, plus the `$` shows up.  If I type `$A\left(Y,X\right)$` it turns out perfectly.  How do I correct this?

I am using Springer Nature template and have added `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  That input would not cause that output.  Could you copy and paste a minimal working example that shows what you're typing?  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you using `\left` and `\right` here?

Comment: I just type the papers.  I don't really know what the math means.  The expression is (X|Y) (X and Y being in italics, of course, when in math mode).  I did learn I can type \left(X \mid Y\right) and get the expression, except that there's too much space on both sides of the |.